# How to get a list of images on docker registry v2

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm using docker registry v1 and I'm interested in migrating to the newer version, v2. But I need some way to get a list of images present on registry; for example with registry v1 I can execute a GET request to `http://myregistry:5000/v1/search?` and the result is:

```
{
  "num_results": 2,
  "query": "",
  "results": [
    {
      "description": "",
      "name": "deis/router"
    },
    {
      "description": "",
      "name": "deis/database"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I can't find on [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/) something similar to get a list of image on registry. Anybody knows a way to do it on new version v2?

Comment: Still not enough.  Need the dates of the image creation and image push, and hopefully include/suppress prior tag versions.  There's got to be an actual web interface, too, right?  I'm talking to our admin - we've only got 2.0

Comment: hub.docker.com seems to have a different API, e.g. to list tags of a repository: `curl -sSX GET 'https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/php/tags?page_size=100'`. Or you can make use of [`docker-hub-api`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docker-hub-api).

Comment: I can't believe docker cli does not have this build in :| you have already logged in via "docker login", so why not provide a command like `docker images ls --in-repo=XXX`

Comment: I'am trying to acces public hub.docker with my private repository, which i added some images on private, but it don't work, if you have any ideas

Answer (score 698, accepted):

For the latest (as of 2015-07-31) version of Registry V2, you can get [this image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/distribution/registry/) from DockerHub:

```
docker pull distribution/registry:master
```

List all repositories (effectively images):

```
curl -X GET https://myregistry:5000/v2/_catalog
> {"repositories":["redis","ubuntu"]}
```

List all tags for a repository:

```
curl -X GET https://myregistry:5000/v2/ubuntu/tags/list
> {"name":"ubuntu","tags":["14.04"]}
```

If the registry needs authentication you have to specify username and password in the `curl` command

```
curl -X GET -u <user>:<pass> https://myregistry:5000/v2/_catalog
curl -X GET -u <user>:<pass> https://myregistry:5000/v2/ubuntu/tags/list
```

By default the [number of images is limited](https://github.com/distribution/distribution/blob/v2.8.3/registry/handlers/catalog.go#L18) to `100`, increase the limit with`?n={new limit}`, if you exceed the default value:

```
curl https://myregistry:5000/v2/_catalog?n=1000
```

Comment: Where do you get the certificate from?

Comment: @duality in case your registry is using either a self-signed certificate, or a certificate signed by an untrusted root CA, you need to supply the certificate to curl to establish a secure connection. To make an insecure connection you could add the '--insecure' flag instead.

Comment: -k, --insecure (SSL)

Comment: Check also which port the docker-registry is using, on the host itself. It may be mapped to 5000 internally, but on the outside, using another one. For me that was the case, as it was using 443:5000, and then the command worked with 443 instead.

Comment: Default result only show 100 images record, but if you need to show more you can paginate the result with this query: `http://<registry-url>/v2/_catalog?n=<count>` with count for example 2000.

Comment: If the registry is password protected, use `curl -u <user>:<pass> -X GET ...`

Comment: No port number required for me to access azurecr.io

Comment: just use `-u <user>` without password on the command line; you will be prompted to type the password, invisibly

Answer (score 122):

you can search on

> http://`<ip/hostname>`:`<port>`/v2/_catalog

Comment: ...as of more recently I'd just like to add that https is required instead of just http

Comment: I see no such need for my recently installed Docker Registry!

Comment: http://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog  -- If you have been following the [Deploy a registry server document](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/).

Comment: Website is not reachable via browser ...

Comment: Docker registry doesnt have any kind of authentication nor authorization (I suspect thats the main selling point of hub.docker) - that why you set up reverse proxy (Traefik, NGINX). And sane reverse proxy will NOT send `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="whatever"` (prompt for BASIC credentials) over http - you certainly wouldn't send `name:password` in cleartext over http, wouldn't you...  So SSL (https) is (when you use BASIC auth) and is not (when you dont) required - but it has nothing to do with registries, but with your reverse proxy.

Answer (score 74):

### Get catalogs

Default, registry api return 100 entries of catalog, there is the [code](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/b6e0cfbdaa1ddc3a17c95142c7bf6e42c5567370/registry/handlers/catalog.go):

When you curl the registry api:

```
curl --cacert domain.crt https://your.registry:5000/v2/_catalog
```

it equivalents with：

```
curl --cacert domain.crt https://your.registry:5000/v2/_catalog?n=100
```

This is a pagination methond.

When the sum of entries beyond 100, you can do in two ways:

**First**: give a bigger number

```
curl --cacert domain.crt https://your.registry:5000/v2/_catalog?n=2000
```

**Second**: parse the next linker url

```
curl --cacert domain.crt https://your.registry:5000/v2/_catalog
```

A link element contained in response header:

```
curl --cacert domain.crt https://your.registry:5000/v2/_catalog
```

response header:

```
Link: </v2/_catalog?last=pro-octopus-ws&n=100>; rel="next"
```

The link element have the last entry of this request, then you can request the next 'page':

```
curl --cacert domain.crt https://your.registry:5000/v2/_catalog?last=pro-octopus-ws
```

If the response header contains **link** element, you can do it in a **loop**.

### Get Images

When you get the result of catalog, it like follows:

```
{
   "repositories": [
      "busybox",
      "ceph/mds"
   ]
}
```

you can get the images in every catalog:

```
curl --cacert domain.crt https://your.registry:5000/v2/busybox/tags/list
```

returns:

```
{"name":"busybox","tags":["latest"]}
```

Comment: 100 entries defined [here](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/b6e0cfbdaa1ddc3a17c95142c7bf6e42c5567370/registry/handlers/catalog.go)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is the only answer that explains how you get around the dreaded pagination. The currently accepted answer (jonatan) only shows images starting with "a".

Comment: and how would you get tags list for `ceph/mds`? in general, for any repository defined with `/` - `/v2/_catalog/ceph/mdt/tags/list` doesn't work

Comment: @tymik we can access tags list for repos containing `/` in their names by using `/v2/ceph/mdt/tags/list` i.e. by omitting `_catalog` (works for repos without `/` as well) ref: https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-image-tags

Answer (score 28):

The latest version of Docker Registry available from https://github.com/docker/distribution supports Catalog API. (v2/_catalog). This allows for capability to search repositories

If interested, you can try docker image registry CLI I built to make it easy for using the **search features** in the new Docker Registry distribution (https://github.com/vivekjuneja/docker_registry_cli)

Answer (score 26):

This has been driving me crazy, but I finally put all the pieces together. As of 1/25/2015, I've confirmed that it is possible to list the images in the docker V2 registry ( exactly as @jonatan mentioned, above. )

I would up-vote that answer, if I had the rep for it.

Instead, I'll expand on the answer. Since registry V2 is made with security in mind, I think it's appropriate to include how to [set it up with a self signed cert](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/insecure.md#using-self-signed-certificates), and [run the container with that cert](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/deploying.md#get-a-certificate) in order that an https call can be made to it with that cert:

This is the script I actually use to start the registry:

```
sudo docker stop registry
sudo docker rm -v registry
sudo docker run -d \
  -p 5001:5001 \
  -p 5000:5000 \
  --restart=always \
  --name registry \
  -v /data/registry:/var/lib/registry \
  -v /root/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \ 
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_DEBUG_ADDR=':5001' \
  registry:2.2.1
```

This may be obvious to some, but I always get mixed up with keys and certs. The file that needs to be referenced to make the call @jonaton mentions above**, is the domain.crt listed above. ( Since I put domain.crt in `/root`, I made a copy into the user directory where it could be accessed. )

```
curl --cacert ~/domain.crt https://myregistry:5000/v2/_catalog
> {"repositories":["redis","ubuntu"]}
```

**The command above has been changed: -X GET didn't actually work when I tried it.

Note: `https://myregistry:5000` ( as above ) must match the domain given to the cert generated.

Answer (score 24):

We wrote a CLI tool for this purpose: [docker-ls](https://github.com/mayflower/docker-ls) It allows you to browse a docker registry and supports authentication via token or basic auth.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a nice little one liner (uses JQ) to print out a list of Repos and associated tags.

If you dont have `jq` installed you can use: `brew install jq`

```
# This is my URL but you can use any
REPO_URL=10.230.47.94:443

curl -k -s -X GET https://$REPO_URL/v2/_catalog \
 | jq '.repositories[]' \
 | sort \
 | xargs -I _ curl -s -k -X GET https://$REPO_URL/v2/_/tags/list
```

Comment: argh, I just wrote this then found yours :S but I'll keep my answer because it shows how to handle Basic auth too, and it explains why it works. Also filters the result into a flat image list.

Comment: Just for in case jq is not in your Linux distro, get it her https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/    It's a very useful little tool.

Answer (score 11):

Install registry:2.1.1 or later (you can check the last one, [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/registry/tags/)) and use GET /v2/_catalog to get list.

https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/spec/api.md#listing-repositories

Lista all images by Shell script example:
https://gist.github.com/OndrejP/a2386d08e5308b0776c0

Comment: You missing the revision number. Currently your link is broken. This is current valid one https://github.com/distribution/distribution/blob/5e75227/docs/content/spec/api.md

Answer (score 10):

I had to do the same here and the above works except I had to provide login details as it was a local docker repository.

It is as per the above but with supplying the username/password in the URL.

```
curl -k -X GET https://yourusername:yourpassword@theregistryURL/v2/_catalog
```

It comes back as unformatted JSON.

I piped it through the python formatter for ease of human reading, in case you would like to have it in this format.

```
curl -k -X GET https://yourusername:yourpassword@theregistryURL/v2/_catalog | python -m json.tool
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's an example that lists all tags of all images on the registry. It handles a registry configured for HTTP Basic auth too.

```
THE_REGISTRY=localhost:5000

# Get username:password from docker configuration. You could
# inject these some other way instead if you wanted.
CREDS=$(jq -r ".[\"auths\"][\"$THE_REGISTRY\"][\"auth\"]" .docker/config.json | base64 -d)

curl -s --user $CREDS https://$THE_REGISTRY/v2/_catalog | \
    jq -r '.["repositories"][]' | \
    xargs -I @REPO@ curl -s --user $CREDS https://$THE_REGISTRY/v2/@REPO@/tags/list | \
    jq -M '.["name"] + ":" + .["tags"][]'
```

Explanation:

- extract username:password from .docker/config.json
- make a https request to the registry to list all "repositories"
- filter the json result to a flat list of repository names
- for each repository name:
- make a https request to the registry to list all "tags" for that "repository"
- filter the stream of result json objects, printing "repository":"tag" pairs for each tag found in each repository

Comment: Nice.  Simple use of the API and plain old shell level tools.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote an [easy-to-use command line tool](https://github.com/andrey-pohilko/registry-cli) for listing images in various ways (like list all images, list all tags of those images, list all layers of those tags).

It also allows you to delete unused images in various ways, like delete only older tags of a single image or from all images etc. This is convenient when you are filling your registry from a CI server and want to keep only latest/stable versions.

It is written in python and does not need you to download bulky big custom registry images.

Answer (score 6):

Using "/v2/_catalog" and "/tags/list" endpoints you can't really list all the images. If you pushed a few different images and tagged them "latest" you can't really list the old images! You can still pull them if you refer to them using digest "docker pull ubuntu@sha256:ac13c5d2...". So the answer is - there is no way to list images you can only list tags which is not the same

Comment: Absolutely. If there are images that don't possess a single tag, and instead only possess digests e.g. `ubuntu@sha256:ac13c5d2`, those will be omitted from the output. If a registry contained `ubuntu@sha256:ac13c5d2`, `alpine:latest`, and `postgres:15.1`, Output from /v2/_catalog would read as `{"repositories":["alpine","postgres"]}`.

Answer (score 4):

If some on get this far.

Taking what others have already said above. Here is a one-liner that puts the answer into a text file formatted, json.

```
curl "http://mydocker.registry.domain/v2/_catalog?n=2000" | jq . - > /tmp/registry.lst
```

This looks like

```
{
  "repositories": [
    "somerepo/somecontiner",
    "somerepo_other/someothercontiner",
 ...
  ]
}
```

You might need to change the `?n=xxxx' to match how many containers you have.

Next is a way to automatically remove old and unused containers.

Answer (score 4):

If, the accepted answer here only returns a blank line, it is likely because of your ssl/tls cert on your registry server.  Use the --insecure flag:

```
curl --insecure https://<registryHostnameOrIP>:5000/v2/_catalog
```

Answer (score 3):

Docker search registry v2 functionality is currently not supported at the time of this writing. See discussion since Feb 2015: "propose registry search functionality #206" https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/206

I wrote a script, view-private-registry, that you can find: https://github.com/BradleyA/Search-docker-registry-v2-script.1.0
It is not pretty but it gets the information needed from the private registry.

Example of output from view-private-registry:

```
$ view-private-registry`
busybox:latest
gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.9
gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v0.21.2
gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0
google/cadvisor:latest
jenkins:latest
logstash:latest
mongo:latest
nginx:latest
python:2.7
redis:latest
registry:2.1.1
stackengine/controller:latest
tomcat:7
tomcat:latest
ubuntu:14.04.2
Number of images:   16
Disk space used:    1.7G    /mnt/three/docker-registry/registry-data
```

Answer (score 3):

This threads dates back a long time, the most recents tools that one should consider are [`skopeo`](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) and [`crane`](https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/tree/master/cmd/crane).

`skopeo` supports signing and has many other features, while `crane` is a bit more minimalistic and I found it easier to integrate with in a simple shell script.

Comment: These are great tools, especially if you have special authentication requirements (e.g. ActiveDirectory).

Answer (score 3):

One liner bash to list all images with their tags:

```bash
curl --user user:pass https://myregistry.com/v2/_catalog | jq .repositories | sed -n 's/[ ",]//gp' | xargs -L1 -IIMAGE curl -s --user user:pass https://myregistry.com/v2/IMAGE/tags/list | jq '. as $parent | .tags[] | $parent.name + ":" + . '
```

Two lines to search for something in the image name:

```bash
search=my_container_part_name
curl --user user:pass https://registry.medworx.io/v2/_catalog | jq .repositories | sed -n '/'"$search"'/{s/[ ",]//gp;}' | xargs -L1 -IIMAGE curl -s --user user:pass https://registry.medworx.io/v2/IMAGE/tags/list | jq '. as $parent | .tags[] | $parent.name + ":" + . '
```

replace: user, pass and myregistry.com accordingly

uses curl, sed, xargs and jq and is hard to understand... but it does the job. It produces one call per image + 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you can ssh or attach to the docker registry container, just browse the filesystem to look for things you want, like:

```bash
kubectl exec -it docker-registry-0 -- /bin/sh

ls /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories
ls /var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/repositories/busybox/_manifests/tags/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple bash script to view and explore a list of catalogs and tags in a self hosted registry. It uses the API exposed in the registry docker image. If you have `jless` installed it makes viewing a little bit nicer.

```
#!/bin/bash
REGISTRY="https://my.registry.internal:5000"

curl -s GET $REGISTRY/v2/_catalog
echo "Enter name to get tags:"
read REPO

if command -v jless &> /dev/null
then
  curl -s GET $REGISTRY/v2/$REPO/tags/list | jless
else
  curl -s GET $REGISTRY/v2/$REPO/tags/list
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each registry runs as a container the container ID has an associated log file ID-json.log this log file contains the vars.name=[image] and vars.reference=[tag]. A script can be used to extrapolate and print these. This is perhaps one method to list images pushed to registry V2-2.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

If your use-case is identifying only **SIGNED** and **TRUSTED** images for production, then this method is handy.

It parses a docker image repo for all **SIGNED** tags and strips away all the JSON formatting, puking-out only clean image tags. Which of course can be processed further according to your requirements.

Format of Command:

```
docker trust inspect imageName | grep "SignedTag" | awk -F'"' '{print $4}'
```

Examples using the nginx & Bitnami Docker repos:

```
docker trust inspect nginx | grep "SignedTag" | awk -F'"' '{print $4}'

docker trust inspect bitnami/java | grep "SignedTag" | awk -F'"' '{print $4}'
```

If there are no signed images then ***No signatures or cannot access imageName*** will be returned.

Example of a repo **WITHOUT** signed images (*at the time of this writing*) using the Wordpress Docker repo:

```
docker trust inspect wordpress | grep "SignedTag" | awk -F'"' '{print $4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a nice web interface to your registry you can use [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/klausmeyer/docker-registry-browser/tags) registry-browser docker image. This is useful if you just want to look around your registry, different repositories and tags.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).