# how do I find all docker images in a private registry that got pushed in the last 6 months?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-registry

I have a docker private registry and docker images in it. Now I would like to copy all the images which are created in last 6 months, to another private  docker registry. Can anyone help me with command/script to find out the docker images which got pushed into the registry in last 6 months? then I can re-tag it and push to the new registry.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If your actual question is "how do I find all the images that got pushed in the last 6 months?", please update the title accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the images. by the following three steps.
1. get the the catalogs from the registry
2. get the Tags for the images from step1
3. get the created date of the image:tag from step 2
4. compare the date

Answer (score 1):

Didn't get the question correctly but
these are some links related to what i understood:

[How to get a list of images on docker registry v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251356/how-to-get-a-list-of-images-on-docker-registry-v2)

https://blog.giantswarm.io/moving-docker-container-images-around/