# How do you list available Docker images for a specific architecture

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, openshift, dockerhub

Trying to pull Docker images to a s390x architecture (available as Hyperprotect VS on IBM public Cloud) and the web based dockerhub search interface doesn't really have a way to only list the specific tags where a Docker image exists for a particular architecture.

I tried `using docker pull`, `docker search`, `docker manifest`, along with some of the "experimental" features. If a Docker image exists, the command will pull it (for example `docker pull node:8.11.2`) but what if I wanted to see what Node images actually were in dockerhub (or any other repository for that matter) for the s390x, arm, ppcle64, architectures?

Ideas anyone?

```
$ docker search node

docker pull node:8.11.2-alpine
8.11.2-alpine: Pulling from library/node
no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries
```

Comment: We can't list architecture specific images from the repo. But you can inspect the docker image after downloading. Possibly a duplicate to list the images - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251356/how-to-get-a-list-of-images-on-docker-registry-v2

Comment: Yes.. but that means that i need to pull container images on to my platform, my case s390x, and the inspect them prior to running them.  If I am looking for a version of nginx to run, I should be able to search for them.  Docker manifest which is a experimental feature helps with this, after the container image is downloaded

Comment: @fossl Is any of the answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251356/how-to-get-a-list-of-images-on-docker-registry-v2 satisfactory enough for you?

Answer (score 1):

I am posting the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251356/how-to-get-a-list-of-images-on-docker-registry-v2):

> For the latest (as of 2015-07-31) version of Registry V2, you can get
>   [this image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/distribution/registry/)
>   from DockerHub:
>
> ```
> docker pull distribution/registry:master
> ```
>
> List all repositories (effectively images):
>
> ```
> curl -X GET https://myregistry:5000/v2/_catalog
> > {"repositories":["redis","ubuntu"]}
> ```
>
> List all tags for a repository:
>
> ```
> curl -X GET https://myregistry:5000/v2/ubuntu/tags/list
> > {"name":"ubuntu","tags":["14.04"]}
> ```

Comment: I know it means you have to pull container images but it seems the best/only option here. Answer was posted for better visibility.