# How to list only images located in a specific, private registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm having problems getting a listing of images from a specific registry that I've set up on a local server, or, maybe, I'm having issues publishing them to that registry in the first place, as this is my first adventure into docker registries, I may just be confused with the terms used.

There's an old question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251356/how-to-get-a-list-of-images-on-docker-registry-v2), that kind of looks like what I want to achieve, but it appears that docker has gained built-in support for this, in the meanwhile, so the methods mentioned here are no longer relevant.

I have 2 servers (for the purpose of this question):

1. **rancher-server:** This server has a `rancher:v2.6.0` container running and a `registry:2` container.
2. **k8s-server:** This is just a freshly installed server, with the docker and kubernetes packages installed, that I want the rancher server to administer.

On **k8s-server**, I'm trying to spin up a docker image `rancher/rancher-agent:v2.6.0` with a few arguments, that should let it relinquish control to the rancher server.

The trick here is, that this is all required to work without internet access (currently there IS internet access, but it's a PoC for a task that requires to be air-gapped). For the purposes of this question, I really just want to be able to spin up docker containers on **k8s-server**, using the registry on rancher-server.

Currently, this is the state of **rancher-server**:

```
# docker ps --all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
b9a15ea00d5e        registry:2          "/entrypoint.sh /e..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp                     local-registry
1b6bc6b88a8e        08c9693b4357        "entrypoint.sh 08c..."   26 hours ago        Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   goofy_minsky

# docker image ls --all (the list is big, this is just a sample):
REPOSITORY                                            TAG    IMAGE ID     CREATED
rancher/rancher-agent                                 v2.6.0 9c35a790aa16 2 weeks ago        
rancher-server.example.com:5000/rancher/rancher-agent v2.6.0 9c35a790aa16 2 weeks ago 

# docker info
Containers: 2
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 225
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: journald
Cgroup Driver: systemd
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: docker-runc runc
Default Runtime: docker-runc
Init Binary: /usr/libexec/docker/docker-init-current
containerd version:  (expected: aa8187dbd3b7ad67d8e5e3a15115d3eef43a7ed1)
runc version: 66aedde759f33c190954815fb765eedc1d782dd9 (expected: 9df8b306d01f59d3a8029be411de015b7304dd8f)
init version: fec3683b971d9c3ef73f284f176672c44b448662 (expected: 949e6facb77383876aeff8a6944dde66b3089574)
Security Options:
 seccomp
  WARNING: You're not using the default seccomp profile
  Profile: /etc/docker/seccomp.json
 selinux
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-1160.41.1.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Number of Docker Hooks: 3
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.701 GiB
Name: rancher-server
ID: SA2T:G2IA:CGER:6BC5:HIV2:4T6T:LF3Q:2YVS:SYU7:SQ5V:ACUS:BMEX
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 rancher-server.example.com:5000
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Registries: docker.io (secure)
```

On the **k8s-server**, I try to list the contents of that registry:

```
# docker image ls --all rancher-server.example.com:5000
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE

# docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: journald
Cgroup Driver: systemd
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: docker-runc runc
Default Runtime: docker-runc
Init Binary: /usr/libexec/docker/docker-init-current
containerd version:  (expected: aa8187dbd3b7ad67d8e5e3a15115d3eef43a7ed1)
runc version: 66aedde759f33c190954815fb765eedc1d782dd9 (expected: 9df8b306d01f59d3a8029be411de015b7304dd8f)
init version: fec3683b971d9c3ef73f284f176672c44b448662 (expected: 949e6facb77383876aeff8a6944dde66b3089574)
Security Options:
 seccomp
  WARNING: You're not using the default seccomp profile
  Profile: /etc/docker/seccomp.json
 selinux
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-1160.41.1.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Number of Docker Hooks: 3
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.701 GiB
Name: k8s-server
ID: QETJ:QSPQ:VS36:OOOA:ZPYL:CDHK:AJ5G:N4BD:ZQUH:UL6O:PHAB:5UOE
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 rancher-server.example.com:5000
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Registries: docker.io (secure)
```

I had to jump through a few hoops to get there, in the first place, marking the registry as unsafe in /etc/docker/daemon.json on the **k8s-server** and disabling selinux on the **rancher-server**, for example.

I've tried to `docker login rancher-server.example.com:5000` first, but that made no difference. It does look like, to me, that the **k8s-server** is configured correctly, but that the images on **rancher-server** haven't been tagged/pushed properly, but when I look back at the registry, I don't know how to do it differently, and, as far as I understand the registry, it looks fine to me?

I've changed the server names for anonymity and the output has been lightly edited for presentation.

**EDIT**:

I think I found a clue to what's happening here, it turns out that I can actually run the images from this registry remotely, just fine, it just so happens that I have no way to discover the names of the images, however, if I do a `docker run -d --privileged --restart=unless-stopped --net=host -v /etc/kubernetes:/etc/kubernetes -v /var/run:/var/run  rancher-server.example.com:5000/rancher/rancher-agent:v2.6.0 --server https://rancher-server.example.com:5000 --token <token> --ca-checksum <ca-checksum> --etcd --controlplane` it actually pulls and runs the container, so it looks like the registry itself is fine, but maybe the index isn't?